# Dark faces in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm trying to get rid of dark faces in Cycles but I can't do it.

[image]

[image]

What I tried to do and it didn't help me:

1. Recalculate inside(outside doesn't do anything). And probably it helped me, but I get strange color somewhere.

[image]

2. Merge vertices -> by Distance - doesn't help me too.

Also you can see my project here: [image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Okay, so, now i found a solution to get rid of these dark faces. I should to delete "mirror". But why? How it works? Then how should i use modifier "mirror"?

Comment: I've not looked at your images because they're on an external site, but the mirror modifier on the Cube object is causing problems because, from the settings it looks as if it should just be on the Boltq object which has its own modifier. The one on the Cube is trying to mirror onto parts that are already there so delete it. The Solidify modifier doesn't seem to be doing much either!

Comment: @Deniss If you don't know how to use the _Mirror_ modifier I would definitely suggest you watch some basic beginner modeling tutorials. In general you can say: you only model on one side (in X, Y or Z direction depending on the mirror settings) of the object origin, the other side will be created by the mirror. If you have vertices and/or faces on both sides, you probably end up with overlapping geometry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have overlapping faces because your have given a *Mirror* modifier to your object and your object has already vertices on the opposite side of its mirror axis, so you either need to remove this modifier or keep it but delete half of your object:

[image]